# 400 Bad Request (Invalid Host) using WCF and mono

Tags: c#, wcf, mono

I am getting a `Bad Request (Invalid host)` when trying to run my C# WCF service under mono.  This service is part of an application, not being hosted using a web server.

I have configured my services with the following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="DefaultServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultServiceBehavior" name="MyServices.TaskService">
      <endpoint address="V1" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyServices.ITaskServiceV1" />
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/MyServices/Tasks" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

When I try to visit `http://localhost:8731/MyServices/Tasks` or any of its endpoints (including `?wsdl`), I get the 400 error.

I have deployed this successfully using the .net runtime, just can't figure out what's wrong for deploying with mono.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** Mono version: 2.10.1

Comment: It's always useful to state the version of Mono you are using... Particularly with WCF, which has seen a lot of changes and improvements 2.4 > 2.6 > 2.8 > 2.10

Comment: Does this happen even if you try to access the service on the same machine?

Comment: This is not technically an answer. But StackOverflow won't let me comment on all posts yet. I am simply wondering if you were able to solve this issue? Since the post if from April, I am hoping that you had some time to figure it out. I am facing the same type of issue as well. In fact I wrote a sample Silverlight app (which the WCF implementation in Mono is supposed to be based on) using the same exact C# code for connecting to the service as is in my Mono app. The Silverlight app had no problems (running from the same machine as the emulator). I am currently running the latest version of Mon

Comment: I still have not gotten an answer...  Honestly, I gave up and generated a WSDL statically that I am deploying to clients.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today. 
Hosting a wcf service inside a .net 3.5 application worked but same code using mono 3.2.2 gives invalid host error response. 
So I checked mono source and found out that mono searches for a valid endpoint from request url using case sensitive compare. Changed my url to fit case like in my service config resolved the issue.